# Corrupted video frames when streaming H264 over RTSP

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264, rtsp

When I stream H264 video over RTSP and use VLC to view the video feed, the video feed is corrupted (partly green but moving objects are still detected). However, if I stop the VLC and restart it again, the video feed is no longer corrupted. Why is it so, and how can I remedy this issue? Thanks!

The H264 is coming natively from a USB camera into a Raspberry Pi. Below is the code within the crontab of the Pi for launching the g-streamer and RTSP server.

`@reboot bash /home/pi/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-launch '( v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-h264, width=320, height=240, framerate=20/1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=98 config-interval=10 )'`

The Raspberry Pi is connected over a network. I am using VLC on another computer to view the video feed.

`vlc rtsp://10.146.0.57:8554/test`

If I reboot the Pi, the video feed on the VLC will be corrupted. I can still see moving objects in the video feed but there will be green and purple pixels all over.

However, if I close the VLC and start VLC again, the issue is gone. The video feed is clean.

The output of VLC:

`[0000557c34211570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Created new TCP socket 35 for connection
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[00007fd9b800df20] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented`

Comment: TL;DR: You're too slow to decode all frames. Long answer: MJPEG does not suffer from it because the decoding is limited to the very frame you are decoding right now. It happens with MP4 (in fact H264) because after decoding a master frame (I frames), you need to decode the little frames called B or P frames and if you have not finished the frames in queue, you'll get distorted frames.

Comment: @CelalErgün Is this related to bitrate? MJPEG has 300kb/s while the H264 has around 4000kb/s. I checked using VLC -> current media information -> content bitrate. I am decoding the frame using a laptop which I believe is fast enough?

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate - you restart the Pi but keep the VLC connection running? Doesn't it disconnect because the RTSP server goes away? VLC *should* reconnect after the Pi restarts. If it does not do this this may be a problem.

If a new H.264 bitstream is initiated by the Pi it is logically different from what it previously has send. If the VLC does not restart but just continues decoding this stream it may get "confused" resulting in decoding error (relying on wrong reference pictures).

H.264 has a temporal dependency for frames. MJPEG does not have this - each frame can be decoded by it self. Therefore you will not see the issue to be present here.

Comment: Here is the exact step I followed: 1- Start the Pi (with crontab) 2- Start the VLC on receiver side, received corrupted frame 3 - Close the VLC on the receiver side 4 - Reboot the Pi 5 - Start the VLC on the receiver side after Pi is fully rebooted, no corrupted frame. Note that if I tried step 2 on one computer and step 5 on another computer, the issue will still go away

Comment: I don't see how 1./2. is any different from 4./5. That should give the same result?

Comment: Do you think this is related to bitrate/network bandwidth? MJPEG has 300kb/s while the H264 has around 4000kb/s. I checked using VLC -> current media information -> content bitrate. Or is there something I missing when launching the gstreamer pipeline?

Comment: I switched to a lower bitrate over the network and the same issue (corrupted feed during initial streaming by VLC) still occurs. Here's the code at the Raspi: `@reboot bash /home/pi/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-launch '( v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videoscale ! videorate ! videoconvert ! x264enc pass=pass1 threads=5 bitrate=300 ! video/x-h264, width=320, height=240, framerate=20/1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=98 config-interval=10 )'`